# Influxdb Query with Cast to Float

Tags: influxdb

My database certainly has some points that I want. It complains that cost is a string (introduced via an old json interface) if I try to sum the data it gives:

```
ERR: unsupported sum iterator type: *influxql.stringInterruptIterator
```

I guess I'm trying to sum a string?

```
> SELECT "cost" from watts order by desc limit 10
name: watts
time                cost
----                ----
2022-09-26T10:16:45.925068962Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:13:33.290878925Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:11:22.681558454Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:07:09.405004296Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:05:42.859464731Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:03:35.006380011Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:02:54.010176738Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T10:00:21.790285285Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T09:59:21.177746381Z  0.0345
2022-09-26T09:58:31.31611238Z   0.0345
```

So, following influxdb doc, I've cast to float and this query below doesn't give any errors, **but no results either**. This must be something really simple, mustn't it? I actually want to get a version of this query into Grafana, currently giving the dreaded *No Data Points*.

```
> SELECT sum("cost"::float) FROM "watts" WHERE time >= 1664146800000ms GROUP BY time(5m)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using InfluxDB v1. InfluxDB does support some cast operations but it doesn't support cast String values to Float values. See more detail [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#cast-operations).

You could rewrite your date with correct data type. That is, instead of writing the cost as String:

```
INSERT watts cost="0.0345"
```

Try to write it as Float (note: remove the double quotes):

```
INSERT watts cost=0.0345
```

Then you can run the sum happily:

```
select sum(cost) from watts
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I've accepted this. In fact, since I'd just started this measurement I deleted the whole series and put  `cost = float(config['data']['cost'])` into the Python script, before formatting the json. It is V1 and I need to update it.

Comment: glad you made it.